# <Custom liquid pc cooling> which pump I need for my loop?

Tags: pc

I have years of experience with aircooled systems and i have build about 10 systems in my life, but now is time to upgrade my own system for first time in 6 years and im going to go all out with water cooling  for first time.

Yes i'am an PC enthusiast, please don't judge me, I just love building stupid systems, but now i would need advice with the water cooling.

---

**I want to know what kind of head pressure i do need with system like this ?
What is the best pump for my loop, may add more GPUs / other components in future.**

---

**I know that my planed system is not good price to performanse** and i have like 60 % more cooling that i should have, but i am just intrested in building the system, i know that one 360mm rad would be optimal for one GPU & CPU.

Here is the system im planing to go for.
I have my 1080 Ti asus turbo from my old system ( found full water block for it )

- i9-9900K ( covered by mono block )
- Asus 1080 ti Turbo ( full block )
- Asus Rog XI extreme ( with EK waterblocks mono block )
- 2 X XSPC EX480 low profile ( 35.5 mm thick )
- Hard tubing ( PETG )
- Thermaltake Level 20 XT big cube case.
- Some flow meter ( not sure about model yet )
- Another GPU in future posibly.

---

Both radiators will be installed to the sealing of the case ( top ).

I have used now about tree weeks to absorbing as much information about the water cooling as possible, but im not completely sure what kind of pump power i need, does one D5 pump do the job or do i need more ?

Originaly i was thinking some alphacool resorvour D5 pump combo by not so sure after i desided to add another rad just for fun basicly.

---

Cooling component list currenlty

- 8 X [Noctua NF-F12 industrialPPC-3000 PWM, 120mm (NF-F12 IPPC-3000 PWM)](https://geizhals.eu/1115511)
- 2 X [Noctua NF-A14 industrialPPC-3000 PWM, 140mm (NF-A14 PPC 3000 PWM)](https://geizhals.eu/1115494)
- 1 X [Noctua NF-P14s redux-1500 PWM,140mm](https://geizhals.eu/1115307)
- 1 X [EK Water Blocks Quantum Line ASUS ROG Maximus XI extreme Monoblock](https://geizhals.eu/2040770)
- 1 X [Alphacool ice pipe Hardtube PETG pipe](https://geizhals.eu/1492178)
- 1 X [Alphacool ice cream cup D5 250mm acetal incl. VPP755 (13308)](https://geizhals.eu/1707054)
     **( Not sure if this pump will be enough )**
- 2 X [XSPC EX480 low profile, black](https://geizhals.eu/697456)

---

(EDIT)
Would something like **[this](https://geizhals.eu/ek-water-blocks-ek-xres-140-ddc-3-2-pwm-elite-a1332500.html?show_description=1)** ( 5.2m head pressure ) be enough right ?
(/EDIT)

Could not find any good tags for the post eather. No liquid cooling or something like that.
Sorry for messy post, bad grammas and typos not my native languange.

Best regards,
Visdmin